# DISTINCT in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

What does the query below give exactly? I have tried to play around with it but don't understand the results generated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT metric, value

    FROM

        Table X
```

If I had just "SELECT DISTINCT metric FROM table X", I understand that it would just return all distinct values in the column metric but what is it doing when you add an extra column to the end (like the above case where we have the column "value")?

Comment: It returns all distinct values of `metric`/`value` that appear in the data.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `distinct` with multiple columns in the `select` clause it acts on all the columns to give you unique combinations of those column values.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of a column meaning more than one column in select with a distinct would treat both the columns together as unique not one column only as if suppose one column has more duplicates than the other then if distinct gives unique for one column and not the other then it would led to inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

The metric and value column will act as a combination here. If the metric=table_name has two tables x, y with different owner then the distinct result will be 
table_name - x
table_name - y